# Cannot compile: unknown type name 'string'

Tags: c

I have a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argCount, string args[])
{
 // ....
}
```

My make file is:

```
TARGET = test
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
     cc -g -std=gnu99 -o $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).c -lm
```

It gives a compilation error: unknown type name 'string' at the args parameter of main.

What else must be included to be able to use string?

Comment: There is no type named `string` in c.

Comment: C uses character arrays instead of strings

Comment: There is no string type in C, use char * of char [] instead.

Comment: This is from the [HarvardX CS50](https://courses.edx.org/courses/HarvardX/CS50x/2014_T1/info) course.  I was trying to run the exercise in my own Ubuntu environment.  The course VM set-up has another #include <cs50.h>.  The course uses string from the beginning, and char * hasn't been mentioned yet.  Whoever down voted the question please reconsider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no type named `string` in c. C language use null-terminated array of characters as strings. So does the whole [string.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Look at any function definition e.g.: [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) - `size_t strlen( const char *str );`.

I guess you could use write a `typedef` for it such as `typedef char* string;` but I would advise against it. It would introduce too much confusion in my opinion.

So your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argCount, const char* args[])
{
 // ....
 return 0; // don't forget it other wise your app will spit some random exit code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type named string in c. 
If it's from school, there's probably an already included typedef somewhere of "string" in a header file:

`#define MAX_CHAR 100
typedef char string[MAX_CHAR+1];`